# Numpy handle memory for large ndarray

Tags: numpy, out-of-memory, numpy-ndarray

I need to run a simulation, generating random numbers with an output in 3 dimensions, *(n_sim, t_horizon, n_loans)* all relatively big.

By default the output is in `float64` and I'm running in out-of-memery issues.

I tested 2 options, both not-conclusive:

- force to allocate memory in `float32`, but depending on the parameters it can be not enough
- reduce the dimensions to 2, iterating for example on n_loans, but making the simulation extremely slow

Is there a 3rd way to fix the memory consumption preserving the runtime?

---

**Edit:**

I generate some random numbers:

```
sample = np.random.gamma( A, B,(n_sim, t_horizon, n_loans))
```

Then I do sums, products, comparisons with given thresholds and at the end I have a loss distribution with size

```
(n_sim, t_horizon, n_loans)
```

because I need all the 3 dimensions for reporting.

Comment: No, there is no general purpose solutions for that. It would be amazing and make big-data application trivial to write. There is a simple generic solution, but not a fast one: mapping the memory on a storage device. I advise you to choose the second case and optimize it using another approach. Unfortunately, we cannot help you further without the actual code since better solutions are only specific ones.

Comment: Thanks. I added some additional details in edit but I guess the answer will be the same. i.e. no

Comment: All the important information lies in "Then I do sums, products, comparisons " which is pretty vague. Regarding the actual operation you can compute things by chunks so to avoid a significant memory usage.